# Building a Strong Web Development Portfolio and Improving Skills for Internship or Job Opportunities in 2024

Tags: helper, web-development-server, intern

Details: I have nearly completed the front-end development for my portfolio but need guidance on how to enhance my chances of securing a web development internship or job in 2024. I lack confidence in my soft skills and want to know the optimal level of data structures and algorithms (DSA) knowledge and JavaScript proficiency required for success in interviews.

Tried and Expected: Yet to build a portfolio, seeking advice on DSA and JavaScript to boost interview readiness.